# Subir automaticamente uma instância de servidor na Amazon se a outra cair

Tags: amazon-aws

Sou novo com aws da amazon, e tive recentemente um problema que caiu minha instância e para resolver tive que criar uma nova instância. Alguém poderia me dizer qual estratégia que eu poderia criar para que se cair minha instância outra entra em execução? O Auto Scaling faz isso? Existe uma opção barata pra isso?

Answer (score 4):

No [EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/pt/ec2/details/) da [Amazon WebServices](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/) você pode criar a instância com 2 tipos de discos. Discos físicos ([EBS](http://aws.amazon.com/pt/ebs/)) e [Discos Efêmeros](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html). Discos físicos são o Disco Magnético e SSD. O disco efêmero é um disco de memória e quando a máquina é desligada, os dados são perdidos. Alguns preferem usar o disco efêmero para swap e outros para produção. Algumas pessoas colocam o site no [GitHub](http://www.github.com/) e configuram auto-publicação no site quando ele sobe e, neste caso, o ganho está exatamente na performance de um disco de memória.

Sim, o *Auto Scaling* permite isso. Você cria um script nele que fará o [balanceamento de carga](http://aws.amazon.com/pt/elasticloadbalancing/) entre instâncias. O *Auto Scaling* não trabalha direto com a instância. Ele trabalha com a imagem AMI. Para usar você precisará criar sua imagem AMI e colocar a referência dela no script. De acordo com o balanceamento configurado por você ele subirá uma instância ou terminará com uma, trazendo a verticalização para cima ou para baixo.

Muito cuidado para criar instâncias do tipo *Spot Request*. Elas são consideradas um leilão. Se o preço da instância ultrapassar o configurado, sua instância será terminada sem avisar. Instâncias reservadas são mais baratas, mas você não pode alterar o tipo de instância depois que reservar e trata-se de um caso para avaliação.

Qual sua instância? Que tipos de volume possui? Tais informações nos ajudarão a te ajudar melhor.

Comment: Boa tarde, obrigado pelo esclarecimento. Por enquanto eu tenho uma instância básica, t2.micro com 40 Giga.